# Java Snake illegal movement if user is fast enough

Tags: java

In Snake moving up means you can only turn left and right. If you're moving left, you can only turn up and down etc. Currently I have an issue where if I'm currently moving LEFT (for example), and I then press either UP or DOWN, and then very quickly press RIGHT, the snake will stay on the same level and crash into itself (although I haven't added crash detection yet). I feel like I would need some kind of buffer (like, if I press UP it won't accept any input until the movement is done, and I can then press RIGHT etc.) I'm pretty much a newbie so I appreciate any help and apologize for my stupidity :-)

[This](https://gyazo.com/425319feaf9be14b44a1418049e1a560) is what happens.

My Snake is an ArrayList of SnakeParts (objects with variables x, y and size), and the movement is done by adding a new SnakePart at the front and then removing one in the back.

Here is the relevant code (I don't think I should be calling Thread.sleep() but at the time I didn't know any other way):

Board.java:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyPressed = e.getKeyCode();
    switch (keyPressed) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            controller.setDirection(1); // UP
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            controller.setDirection(2); // DOWN
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            controller.setDirection(3); // LEFT
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            controller.setDirection(4); // RIGHT
            break;
    }
}
```

Controller.java:

```
public void gameLoop() {
    while (!isWon) {
        moveSnake();
        checkCollision();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        }
        board.repaint();
    }
}

public void setDirection(int direction) {
    switch (direction) {
        case 1: // UP
            if (this.direction != 2) // If not going DOWN.
                this.direction = direction;
            break;
        case 2: // DOWN
            if (this.direction != 1) // If not going UP.
                this.direction = direction;
            break;
        case 3: // LEFT
            if (this.direction != 4) // If not going RIGHT.
                this.direction = direction;
            break;
        case 4: // RIGHT
            if (this.direction != 3) // If not going LEFT.
                this.direction = direction;
            break;
    }
}

private void moveSnake() {
    switch (direction) { // Add new part in front.
        case 1:
            snake.add(0, new SnakePart(snake.get(0).getX(), snake.get(0).getY() - (Board.SNAKE_SIZE + 1), Board.SNAKE_SIZE));
            break;
        case 2:
            snake.add(0, new SnakePart(snake.get(0).getX(), snake.get(0).getY() + (Board.SNAKE_SIZE + 1), Board.SNAKE_SIZE));
            break;
        case 3:
            snake.add(0, new SnakePart(snake.get(0).getX() - (Board.SNAKE_SIZE + 1), snake.get(0).getY(), Board.SNAKE_SIZE));
            break;
        case 4:
            snake.add(0, new SnakePart(snake.get(0).getX() + (Board.SNAKE_SIZE + 1), snake.get(0).getY(), Board.SNAKE_SIZE));
            break;
    }
    snake.remove(snake.size() - 1); // Remove last part.
}
```

SnakePart.java:

```
public SnakePart(int x, int y, int size) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = size;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add a variable to your controller called oldDirection. and set it to 0.

in moveSnake() add a line

```
 this.oldDirction = this.direction
```

in setDirection() change your check to be something like

```
  if (this.oldDirection != 3) // If not going LEFT.
```

Also try not to use magic numbers, instead use an enum instead

```
public enum Direction {
    Up, Down, Left, Right
}
```

Comment: Dang, Seconds too slow.

Comment: This works. Thanks for the tip on enums as well! I was a bit confused as to how enums worked but they seem very useful now :-)

Answer (score 1):

You will need a message queue. A flag won't work, because it means new keypresses will be ignored. Here is code:

```
                public Queue<Integer> directions;

                public void gameLoop() {
                    directions=new LinkedList<Integer>();
                    while (!isWon) {
                           updateInput();
                        moveSnake();
                        checkCollision();
                        try {

                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                        }
                        board.repaint();
                    }
                }

                public void setDirection(int dir) {
                    directions.add(dir);
                }

                public void updateInput() {
                    if(directions.isEmpty())
                       return;
                    switch (directions.remove()) {
                        case 1: // UP
                            if (this.direction != 2) // If not going DOWN.
                                this.direction = direction;
                            break;
                        case 2: // DOWN
                            if (this.direction != 1) // If not going UP.
                                this.direction = direction;
                            break;
                        case 3: // LEFT
                            if (this.direction != 4) // If not going RIGHT.
                                this.direction = direction;
                            break;
                        case 4: // RIGHT
                            if (this.direction != 3) // If not going LEFT.
                                this.direction = direction;
                            break;
                    }
                }

                private void moveSnake() {
                    switch (direction) { // Add new part in front.
                        case 1:
                            snake.add(0, new SnakePart(snake.get(0).getX(), snake.get(0).getY() - (Board.SNAKE_SIZE + 1), Board.SNAKE_SIZE));
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            snake.add(0, new SnakePart(snake.get(0).getX(), snake.get(0).getY() + (Board.SNAKE_SIZE + 1), Board.SNAKE_SIZE));
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            snake.add(0, new SnakePart(snake.get(0).getX() - (Board.SNAKE_SIZE + 1), snake.get(0).getY(), Board.SNAKE_SIZE));
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            snake.add(0, new SnakePart(snake.get(0).getX() + (Board.SNAKE_SIZE + 1), snake.get(0).getY(), Board.SNAKE_SIZE));
                            break;
                    }
                    snake.remove(snake.size() - 1); // Remove last part.
                }
```

Comment: Sorry, for some reason, code format is not working on my andrpid device

Answer (score 0):

Create an integer:

```
public int keyDelay = 0;
```

Every time a key is pressed, set that integer to a value above zero:

```
keyDelay = 8;
```

You'll have to experiment a bit to find the right value, if it's too low this fix won't work, if it's too high you can't change direction again for a period of time after you've changed direction.

Every tick (cycle of your game loop) decrement the value if it's above zero:

```
if (keyDelay > 0)
    keyDelay--;
```

Now for the final step, make sure you can only change directions if the keyDelay is zero. An easy way to do this is by wrapping the entire setDirection method in an if statement:

```
if (keyDelay == 0) {
    // Set direction
}
```

Comment: Instead of this, just set a flag when the snake has progressed one 'block' than it previously has. Magic numbers are terrible and it'll be a pain in the future for debugging and upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Have a flag `bool willMoveSoon = false;`

In `setDirection()` include `willMoveSoon = true;`

In `keyPressed()` wrap your whole function in `if (!willMoveSoon) { ... }` - this will ignore keypresses while you are waiting to move the snake

In `moveSnake()` include `willMoveSoon = false;`